# I'm trying to automate some steps I perform in Pages

Tags: applescript, automator, pdf, pages

I use Pages to write my invoices and save a PDF version as well.

Currently, when I'm done, I press Command-S to save, Command-P to bring up the print dialog, select "Save as PDF…" from the PDF menu in the bottom left corner, then I navigate to the correct folder (e.g. ~/Invoices/2017/Open/) and then press Save. Then I close the Pages file and prepare an email to the client with the PDF attached.

I'd love to have a way (with a shortcut?) to perform these steps automatically.

I'm guessing I need to use Automator, but do I create a Workflow, an Application or a Service? Most examples I've found start with a Finder item, not an open document. Or should I be using AppleScript?

Comment: If you didn't know, you can also save a Pages document as a PDF with File > Export To > PDF. You can also assign a keyboard shortcut to that in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts.

Comment: I'm sure I saw it before, but didn't process it. But, I'd still like to find a way to have one shortcut or a script or whatever that does several steps. Like macros in MS Office.